# Scroll-bar cursor mode in text area (for google chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have already implement text area, so that text area had two modes. read-only mode and edit mode. in read-only mode, i have been set the cursor mode to read only 
ex:- (CSS code) `cursor: not-allowed;` but scroll bar cursor mode also giving read-only symbol. i have attached screen shots for your reference. is there are way to change cursor mode only for the scroll bar? i want to change only scroll bar cursor mode to default mode ex:- `cursor: default ;`[image: text-area-cursor-mode][image: text-area-cursor-mode in scroll-bar]

Comment: The element which holds/has text area is same as the element which has scroll property defined for it ?

Comment: Yes, while reducing  the window/screen scroll bar automatically add for the text area.

Comment: Then obviously cursor not allowed will be active for scroll bar as well. Wrap the text area in a div element and set cursor: not allowed only for that div.

Comment: wrapping with div wont work @Yogita088,as the cursor will be in edit mode when you move over text area.

Comment: @Eashan can you share a fiddle of the code ?

Comment: I cant make exact situation but i mean this type of text area my scenario working fine on Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE 

https://jsfiddle.net/b6gbkndh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We have to add two division tags one for whole div and one for the
>   text area like this with two classes

```
<div class="form-control readonly-form-text">
  <div class="readonly-form-text-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
  </div>
</div>
```

and we have to give unique attributes to each CSS classes

```
.form-control readonly-form-text {
   overflow: auto; 
   cursor: default !important; 
}

.readonly-form-text-content {
   cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

This is the screen shots to get an idea

[image: Main div tag]
[image: Special div tag to add text]

Answer (score 0):

In `<textarea>`, you can't handle the scroll-bar cursor, When you have already change cursor(ex:-cursor:not-allowed).

[Google chrome has same open issue.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290466)